# Unable to clone from GitHub enterprise in Jenkins

Tags: windows, git, jenkins

Jenkins build process fails with the following GIT error. And this seems to fail only for this GitHub Enterprise repository. If I try to do the same for GitHub repository, all ends well.

```
Building in workspace D:\Program Files(x86)\Jenkins\workspace\pullcodefromgithub
Cloning the remote Git repository
Cloning repository https://githubenterprise.grangeinsurance.com/hmb/sail-server.git
 > git.exe init D:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\pullcodefromgithub # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://githubenterprise.grangeinsurance.com/hmb/sail-server.git
 > git.exe --version # timeout=10
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials 
 > git.exe fetch --tags --progress https://githubenterprise.grangeinsurance.com/hmb/sail-server.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
ERROR: Timeout after 10 minutes
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git.exe fetch --tags --progress https://githubenterprise.grangeinsurance.com/hmb/sail-server.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code -1:
stdout: 
stderr: 
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1784)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1513)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$300(CliGitAPIImpl.java:64)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:315)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$2.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:512)
        at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1054)
        at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1094)
        at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:495)
        at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1278)
        at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:604)
        at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
        at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:529)
        at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1728)
        at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
        at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
        at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:404)
ERROR: null
Finished: FAILURE
```

Note: This is not gitHub, but GitHub enterprise. Not sure how to fix it. No matter where I try - Mac or Windows, error is the same. Tried the same with SSH and that also fails

```
Started by user Ram
Building in workspace D:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\pullcodefromgithub
 > git.exe rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git.exe config remote.origin.url https://githubenterprise.grangeinsurance.com/hmb/sail-server.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://githubenterprise.grangeinsurance.com/hmb/sail-server.git
 > git.exe --version # timeout=10
using GIT_SSH to set credentials 
 > git.exe fetch --tags --progress https://githubenterprise.grangeinsurance.com/hmb/sail-server.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
ERROR: Timeout after 10 minutes
ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Failed to fetch from https://githubenterprise.grangeinsurance.com/hmb/sail-server.git
        at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:803)
        at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1063)
        at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1094)
        at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:495)
        at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1278)
        at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:604)
        at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
        at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:529)
        at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1728)
        at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
        at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
        at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:404)
Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git.exe fetch --tags --progress https://githubenterprise.grangeinsurance.com/hmb/sail-server.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code -1:
stdout: 
stderr: 
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1784)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1513)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$300(CliGitAPIImpl.java:64)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:315)
        at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:801)
        ... 11 more
ERROR: null
Finished: FAILURE
```

If I try to pull the contents of the repository from terminal or command prompt or git shell, it seems to work without any issues.

I am clueless to what is going on here. Any help or advice would be greatly helpful.

Thanks

Comment: It might be waiting for the entering of a password/passphrase.  Are you sure the user running the command has the proper ssh-key added?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue happens because of jenkins using "git" in stead of "jgit". This change will bring the universe back to sanity. Here's how we do it

Manage Jenkins-> Global configuration tool
Proceed to "git" section and Tap on "Add Git" drop down button, select JGit
Save your changes

Manage Jenkins -> Browse into your project/item -> Configure
Go into the repository configuration section
Git executable - change from default to jgit
Save your changes and proceed to build

This time, build should succeed. Happy building.